# How to duplicate a record in sql statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I use a sql case statement (PostgreSQL). If there are two types of speeds the row should be duplicated. So that I have two rows with same id but different speed values.

For example the result of my query is:

```
 id | speed    | special_speed       | type
----|----------|---------------------|--------
 1  |     180  |       90            |  0
```

now I will have two rows with either the speed vallue or the special speed value like:

```
id | speed    | type
---|----------|---------
 1 |  180     |  0
 1 |   90     |  0
```

It is required for my work. How can I just duplicate the row in sql?
I have to do this with all resulting rows...

Iam using this kind of statement:

```
    SELECT   a.link_id,

    CASE
        WHEN a.From_Ref_Speed_Limit is null and a.To_Ref_Speed_Limit is not null THEN a.To_Ref_Speed_Limit
        WHEN a.From_Ref_Speed_Limit is not null and a.To_Ref_Speed_Limit is null THEN a.From_Ref_Speed_Limit
        WHEN a.From_Ref_Speed_Limit < a.To_Ref_Speed_Limit THEN a.To_Ref_Speed_Limit
        WHEN a.From_Ref_Speed_Limit > a.To_Ref_Speed_Limit THEN a.From_Ref_Speed_Limit
        WHEN a.From_Ref_Speed_Limit = a.To_Ref_Speed_Limit THEN a.To_Ref_Speed_Limit
        ELSE 0 --unknown
    END as SpeedLimit,

    CASE            
        WHEN a.speed_limit_source = '1' THEN 1 --explizit/posted
        WHEN a.speed_limit_source = '2' THEN 2 --implicit/derived
        ELSE 0 --unknown
    END as LegalType,

    CASE
        WHEN d.dependent_speed_type = 1 THEN 1
        WHEN d.dependent_speed_type = 2 THEN 2
        WHEN d.dependent_speed_type = 3 THEN 3
        WHEN d.dependent_speed_type = 7 THEN 4
        WHEN d.dependent_speed_type = 4 THEN 5
        ELSE 0 -- not related to special situations
    END as LimitType,

    CASE 
        WHEN g.automobiles = 'Y' AND g.trucks = 'Y' AND g.motorcycles = 'Y' THEN 0 
        WHEN g.automobiles = 'Y' AND g.trucks = 'N' AND g.motorcycles = 'N' THEN 1
        WHEN g.automobiles = 'N' AND g.trucks = 'Y' AND g.motorcycles = 'N' THEN 2 
        WHEN g.automobiles = 'N' AND g.trucks = 'N' AND g.motorcycles = 'Y' THEN 3
        ELSE -1
    END as vehicleTypes,

    CASE        
        WHEN d.dependent_speed_type = 4 THEN (SELECT t.time_domain FROM rdf_euw_2015_q4_here_7_10.rdf_time_domain t WHERE d.condition_id = t.feature_id)-- feature_id in RDF_Time_Domain represents condition_id in RDF_Condition
        ELSE ''
    END as timedomain

--INTO rdf_euw_2015_q4_here_7_10.speed_limits_test_LUX

FROM rdf_euw_2015_q4_here_7_10.rdf_nav_link a 


JOIN rdf_euw_2015_q4_here_7_10.rdf_nav_strand l ON a.link_id = l.link_id
JOIN rdf_euw_2015_q4_here_7_10.rdf_condition f ON l.nav_strand_id = f.nav_strand_id
JOIN rdf_euw_2015_q4_here_7_10.rdf_condition_speed d ON f.condition_id = d.condition_id
JOIN rdf_euw_2015_q4_here_7_10.rdf_access g ON f.access_id = g.access_id
```

And therefore if d.special_speed_limit is not empty he has to duplicate the row with the value from d.special_speed_limit inside the column SpeedLimit. Where is the best place to add the union statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is simply `union all`:

```
select id, speed, type
from t
union all
select id, special_speed, type
from t;
```

You can make this conditional by adding a `where`:

```
select id, speed, type
from t
union all
select id, special_speed, type
from t
where special_speed is not null;
```

Under most circumstances, this would meet the needs with two columns.  However, if scanning the table more than once is an issue, you can do:

```
select id, unnest(array(t.speed, t.special_speed)) as speed, type
from t;
```

This uses Postgres's array functionality so the table is scanned only once.

Probably the easiest way to filter this is:

```
select t.*
from (select id, unnest(array(t.speed, t.special_speed)) as speed, type
      from t
     ) t
where speed is not null;
```

Comment: The OP would need to clarify, but this may not be what he had in mind. The UNION ALL will statement will create two records for every record in the table: one for the first select and another for the second select. He may have meant that a second result should be added only when the special_speed is different from the first speed.

Comment: @ACR . . . Thank you for pointing that out.  I edited the answer.